# Showing that $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} \sim e^{-(n+1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to show that:

$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} \sim e^{-(n+1)^2}$$

We have:

$$ \forall p\geq2$$

$$ \exp((n+1)^2-(n+p)^2)=\exp(2n(1-p)+1-p^2)=o(1)$$

$$ e^{-(n+p)^2}=o \left( e^{-(n+1)^2} \right)$$

So:

$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} =e^{-(n+1)^2}+o \left( e^{-(n+1)^2} \right)\sim e^{-(n+1)^2}$$

Given that there are infinitely many $ o \left(e^{-(n+1)^2} \right)$, can the equality 
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} =e^{-(n+1)^2}+o \left( e^{-(n+1)^2} \right) $$ be directly written?

Comment: You have $n$ as the summing index but not in the expression that is being summed...

Comment: It can't be written this way - summing infinitely many $o(a_n)$ can give any result not neccessary $o(a_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $e^{-k^2}<\int_{k-1}^k e^{-x^2}dx$ for $k\ge1$ and $\frac d{dx} e^{-x^2}= -2x e^{-x^2}$, we see (for $n>-1$)
$$\sum_{k=n+2}^\infty e^{-k^2}< \int_{n+1}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx<  \frac1{2(n+1)}\int_{n+1}^\infty 2xe^{-x^2}\,dx =\frac{e^{-(n+1)^2}}{2(n+1)},$$
hence 
$$1<\frac{\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-k^2}}{e^{-(n+1)^2}}<1+\frac1{2(n+1)}.$$
The estimate is not impressively sharp because we use the very rough estimate $e^{-x^2}<\frac x{n+1}e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer, I like the inequality with the integrals!

Answer (score 2):

You can sharpen your first identity to 
$$ 
\exp((n+1)^2 - (n+p)^2) = \exp(2n(1-p) + 1 - p^2) \le \exp(-2n(p-1))   
$$ 
for all $p \ge 2$. Therefore,
$$
1 \le e^{(n+1)^2} \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty e^{-k^2} \le 1 + \sum_{p=2}^\infty e^{-2n(p-1)}
= 1 + \frac{e^{-2n}}{1 - e^{-2n}}\, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hans Engler!